# How to create a catch-all object proxy?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a proxy object that intercepts all property retrievals and function calls, and returns `undefined`.

Accomplishing the former is trivial:

```
const proxy = new Proxy({}, { get: () => undefined });
proxy.foo // undefined
```

In fact, I don't even need a proxy for this, an empty object (`{}`) will do the same. However, doing the same for function calls throws an error:

```
proxy.foo() // TypeError: proxy.foo is not a function
```

I could have the `get` trap return a function:

```
const proxy = new Proxy({}, { get: () => () => undefined });
proxy.foo() // undefined
proxy.foo // [Function]
```

But as you can see, it will return a function instead of `undefined` for my original property access case. Is it possible to accomplish what I want?

```
const proxy = ???;
proxy.foo; // undefined
proxy.foo(); // undefined
```

The end goal is to use this as a "catch-all" stub for testing.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @Bergi for his answer. The following code accomplishes what I want:

```
const proxy = new Proxy(new Function, {
  get: (target, prop, receiver) => receiver,
});

console.log('proxy.foo', proxy.foo); // undefined
console.log('proxy.foo()', proxy.foo()); // undefined
console.log('proxy.foo.bar', proxy.foo.bar); // undefined
console.log('proxy.foo.bar()', proxy.foo.bar()); // undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. A proxy does not intercept *method* calls, it can only intercept calls to the proxy itself (as in `proxy()`). A method call is just a property access followed by a function call to the property value. And it's impossible to have a value that is both `undefined` and a function.

To have a truly catch-all stub for testing, your proxy should return itself (or better, another proxy) for any access or call so that you can have arbitrary chains.

Answer (score 0):

Just to achieve only what you want, you can do this.

```
var obj = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    fooFunc: () => {
        return "this is fooFunc";
    },
    barFunc: () => {
        return "this is barFunc";
    }
}

let Proxy = function (object) {

    for(var prop in object) {
        if(typeof object[prop] === 'function') {
            this[prop] = () => {
                return undefined;
            }
        }
        else {
            this[prop] = undefined;
        }
    }
}

let proxy = new Proxy(obj);

console.log(obj.foo);
console.log(proxy.foo);

console.log(obj.fooFunc());
console.log(proxy.fooFunc());
```

This isn't ideal to customize stubbing approaches but this works for your case I suppose.